# How to write the external javascript file which is useble for both browser and node server with out rewrite code

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, validation, express

Here the following code for validate the form control. I write this for front end validation. How can I reuse this validate.js file for node server for back end validation without rewrite the same validation code for node server.

Here my Validate.js

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    zigzag: function () {
        if( $(this).val()>10)return true;
        else return false;
    }
});
```

and I used this in html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if($('#in').zigzag()){console.log('true');}
        else{console.log('false');}
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="in" type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <button>click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The way you use zigzag makes no sense. It returns a boolean and you compare that to 10

Comment: so, you've shown how you use it in the client, how do you currently do the same thing in the server

Comment: app.post('/',function (req, res, next) {
 if( req.params.lname>10)
 res.end('true');
 else
 res.end('false');
});